# Inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: code-golf, trigonometry

There are 3 (commonly used) trigonometric functions `sin` `cos` and `tan` each of these functions has an inverse function

You goal is to write 3 programs or functions (one for each inverse trigonometric function `asin` `acos` `atan`) that take a (real) number a input and return the result of the corresponding inverse trigonometric function

### Examples/Test-cases (rounded to four decimal places)

```
 x         asin(x)        acos(x)   atan(x)
 
 0         0              1.5708       0
 1         1.5708         0            0.7854
-1        -1.5708         3.1416      -0.7854
 0.2       0.2014         1.3694       0.1974
 0.4       0.4115         1.1593       0.3805
 0.6       0.6435         0.9273       0.5404
-0.5      -0.5236         2.0944      -0.4636
-0.7      -0.7754         2.3462      -0.6107
// you do not need to support these inputs for asin&acos
2      1.5708-1.317i      -1.317i      1.1071
5      1.5708-2.292i      -2.292i      1.3734
10     1.5708-2.993i      -2.993i      1.4711
15     1.5708-3.400i      -3.400i      1.5042
20     1.5708-3.688i      -3.688i      1.5208
100    1.5708-5.298i      -5.298i      1.5608
```

### Rules

- Please add built-in solutions to the community wiki
- You may declare multiple functions in the same program, if you provide a way to choose which of the trigonometric functions is applied to the argument (e.g function names, a second argument)
- It is allowed to return a tuple containing the results of multiple functions
- You may take a second parameter, to distinguish between different functions
- Your solutions for `asin`/`acos` only have to work for arguments between `-1` and `1` (inclusive)
- Your solution only has to be accurate up to three decimal places
- Your score is the sum of the lengths of your program(s)/function(s)

### Optional additional requirements

- Also support inputs that give a complex result
- Do not use the complex logarithm *(see the [Sandbox Post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/25969#25969) for how the complex logarithm might be useful)*

Comment: I'm confused about the "three programs/functions" bit; should we have three separate submissions and add the scores? Should we have one program that defines three functions?

Comment: @noodleman You are allowed to declare your functions in the same program, or declare multiple different programs, depending on what is more convenient

Comment: Is it acceptable to create a single function that returns a tuple with all 3 values?

Comment: @bsoelch That sucks, then you would need to duplicate the logic in all languages that don't have the concept of functions. Which will basically be the same as the ones that don't have built-ins for this

Comment: Can you create a single function that takes a second argument a number so that 1 will be arccos, 2 arcsin, and 3 arctan?

Comment: @mousetail Yes, see rule 2

Comment: What's the difference between `myFunc(0.3)[1]` vs `myFunc(0.3, 1)`? Why is the former banned but the latter allowed?

Comment: @mousetail Tuples are now allowed

Comment: Where did the punctuation go?

Answer (score 8):

### Built-in solutions

#### [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 1 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
○
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=ezS9GwA&f=q3jUNsFAwVDh0HpDBQM9IyA2AWIzIN9AzxRMmisYKZgqGAIVmSoYAUkDA65HvZ0a6hXqCuqJxZl5GhWaIFZyfjGUVZIIFtPUedS7CogOrdB41NVUoakDsuLQeiMgNlZIO7RCASQKAA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Left argument chooses function:

```
¯1○⍵ ⍝ asin
¯2○⍵ ⍝ acos
¯3○⍵ ⍝ atan
```

#### C, 31 Bytes

```
#include<math.h>
asin
acos
atan
```

#### C++, 30 Bytes

```
#include<cmath>
asin
acos
atan
```

#### [Go](https://go.dev)

##### 28 bytes (reals only)

```go
import."math"
Asin
Acos
Atan
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU5BasMwELzrFUIQkGBtZBOnpaCDf5B7W8oiqtSkloK8CYbgl_RiCr31A31Kf9NtUtPDzs4suzvz9r5L89cB_R53z7LHLoquP6RMpQo9qY8jheL22yyzHulFiRNmLQbXDrztXevTIMi1hFGYv4PPcIz-8k4beRYhZfkEo7xzMmNko_vH8JqQNuuzhQqKCmxZc625NlDYsvmFG6ihgYo3GqgZrZ34l5Tb3EUKWiH761UwbhUeCDnFv-Asi4gK5Ahy0KO5EL8QYmLEJKZr5nm-9h8)

##### 34 bytes (includes complex numbers)

```go
import."math/cmplx"
Asin
Acos
Atan
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU5BasMwELzrFUIQkGDtyKZOQ0AH_6D3phQhosSkkoysBEHwS3IxhZ577lP6m26Tmh52dnbZmZ3r-z5MX702R73fUac7TzrXh5hKZl1iH6dki_X3ct45nQ5L4_q3zMhZR04G1Q6oMao1YSBJtUl7Iv5kn_bkzc2UC3ohNkT6CpluFI3a47vnFxPQa5eren2RUEFRgSxrrAesFRSybH7hEWpooMKLBmpEKUe0o_Qpdj5ZzjRG4Asr1MJuk8Yg_wPGmQfPgGagA8_iRsxMEhJBRjLeY0_Tvf8A)

#### JavaScript, 29 bytes

```javascript
Math.asin
Math.acos
Math.atan
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVC7TgMxEBStv8Jy5RV31h0KEAmFAol00FDyUIzPASOfffiBwrfQpIC_gA-Br4nvHAUCFGvNjsazs_vyamwjl583whofsDJdDHiCnXyMyklK5p4Ac5I3U6XlxbMRtCowiWE-TrzvtAqUXJmEW97R89jeSgdHKJs56aMOPtnN3tKPcvxxxsM9414ZlJGwfo0CN1nztXMyY8Gplv71n0cj8OQ4pxwY-cT1QAOsx1otmbZ3lCwI63hzaho6BryLST-WLmDD1lWmU4b_6BToFw1b_tvdetV0qSYKSSkXosAiOujjIoxTP-SlWhlZYDXwPU6zkuxSXbNgp2ohGzqCrZnFj21N_8tslDV8bwjAHmxacDgW5FMu3ytUo7JGFdtLNUp1gMqK7ffPYdasAA)

#### Pascal, 6 bytes (only arctan)

```
arctan
```

Unfortunately, there is no built-in function to *inverse* the operations of `sin` and `cos`. See the [Pascal submission](/a/264796) for a full implementation of the task.

#### [Python](https://www.python.org), 32 bytes (reals only)

```python
from math import*
asin
acos
atan
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY31dKK8nMVchNLMhQycwvyi0q0uIptE4sz87iSbROT84u5SmwTSxLzoKrvpuUXKVQoZOYpRBvoGOroGuoY6BkBsQkQm-noGuiZggjzWCsuBYWCosy8Eo00JZBhGtUVVia1mrbVxRoVmlZ6pmm1MSUg0-HiyUjiQOvg4iUwcSVNLoTdRjqmOoZAB5jqGAFJAwOc9tnHlKBaBBHAYQPEk7CgAQA)

#### [Python](https://www.python.org), 33 bytes (includes complex numbers)

```python
from cmath import*
asin
acos
atan
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY31dOK8nMVknMTSzIUMnML8otKtLiKbROLM_O4km0Tk_OLuUpsE0sS86DKe9LyixQqFDLzFKINdAx1dA11DPSMgNgEiM10dA30TEGEuY6RjqmOIVCFqY4RkDQwiLXiUlAoKMrMK9FIUwKZrlFdYWVaq2lbXaxRoWmlZ5pWG1MCsg4unowkDrQfLl4CE1fShLgJ5hUA)

#### Rust, 29 bytes

```
f64::asin
f64::acos
f64::atan
```

#### [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 14 bytes

```
sin_
cos_
tan_
```

[Try it on scline!](https://scline.fly.dev/##H4sIALRD8WQCA4s2UDBUMIxX0DNS0DNR0DNT0DMFcszjFWL1uKIVYooz8.IVYpLzi4FkSSKQHasQqGCi52eXolCUm1gAADMLI8g.AAAA)

#### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md) each

```
Æs # arcsin
Æc # arccos
Æt # arctan
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSU1QiZjb2RlPSVDMyU4NnMlMEElM0IlMEElQzMlODZjJTBBJTNCJTBBJUMzJTg2dCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PS0wLjUmZmxhZ3M9)

#### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes each

```
∆S # Arcsine
∆C # Arccosine
∆T # Arctangent
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLiiIZTXG7iiIZDXG7iiIZUIiwiIiwiIl0=)

#### [PHP](https://php.net/), 14 bytes

```php
asin
acos
atan
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBagMhEIbvPoUsPaQha2Z0HFda6IO0PciSsoWSXbohl9Jn36okrg0ZcBz//xscnYZpeX6ZYl4@xu9D6IfNK@wk7mQbFyidEqXEUQJlc3bvMszy4Ry@Hn@EjHHohzGfpZJNEppYhPnzuMnQP7Uf5zvqKVTs27F5Er9C7LcC5DXWKgcq66C7ekLifeemL87eWRJtodsb2igk5It3odM/lH4NSNVVhj0VD73L9KoQoq1otN4Uz3RgE81FYTK2GtVrt9KWIM4d9zKb1YYLrRV4ouIRG060W1/iLFW0IdbFYwQntvvlDw)

#### [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 36 bytes

```zsh
zmodload zsh/mathfunc
asin
acos
atan
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYlBCoAgFAWv8hZFuqg0CIKu0kYMUahvpEF4eaNaRJsZhknB5pxWPy9ezUjBtquK1hyks/E7TjhCLVGLpofATTli2x1Fg6qUXTMY/DRRhYIxFRyxk3P@hPbhi6jeky8)

Comment: Any expression that creates a function counts

Comment: If the Python solution is allowed to just dump the functions into the global namespace, without ever actually typing the names of the functions, then how come other languages where the functions are already defined have to type out the names of the functions? Like in Vyxal surely one could argue that the solution is just 0 bytes long because the language already "provide[s] a way to choose which of the trigonometric functions is applied to the argument (e.g function names)", with the "function names" being `∆S` etc.?

Comment: @Lecdi “You goal is to write 3 programs or functions […]” I think the editors misunderstood the goal. You need to make certain functionality _available_ but you do not have to _apply_ the functions. Hence the scoring for programming languages that do not require a dedicated import can be indeed **0 bytes**.

Comment: So this is just a collection with built ins with no imports (0 bytes), or the import statement?

Comment: @infinitezero Yeah, I guess so. This will also aide _comparability_ should one decide to provide a _custom_ (non-built-in) implementation. Otherwise it’s like comparing apples with oranges. You know, _this_ is [tag:code-golf], so the shortest code in bytes achieving the goal wins. The purpose of a community wiki post is probably also to _exclude_ built-ins from [tag:code-golf] competition since they almost always will be shorter.

Comment: Not that it matters too much for this CW builtin collection, but I do believe the scoring for imported functions is incorrect. The function names should be included ([relevant meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8288/64121), quite old but didn't find anything newer)

Comment: The C++ solution is incorrect.  `<cmath>` gets you `std::asin`, `std::acos`, `std::atan`.  For the unqualified names it's `<math.h>` just like C.  Specific implementations may relax this and provide both sets of names from `<cmath>` but then the toolchain needs to be described.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Per standard practice in code-golf, an answer has to work on *at least one* implementation of the language.  For non-portable usage, it's definitely good to say which one, though, especially in an answer like this which is just a catalogue of functions and is missing a https://tio.run/ or https://godbolt.org/ or other live link which implies a specific implementation. (GCC and Clang at least do provide bare names in the global namespace like `asin` even when you include `<cmath>`.) IIRC, ISO C++ doesn't guarantee that a `<math.h>` exists; it's an extension found in many C/C++ impls

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 45 bytes

```r
\(x,f,y=0:4e8/1e8)y[match(T,(f(y)-x)^2<1e-7)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGKzLyykqLMdNulpSVpuhY3dWM0KnTSdCptDaxMUs31DVPNNSujcxNLkjM0QnQ00jQqNXUrNOOMbAxTdc00Y6GaIpM1Eosz8zQM9Ew1daAGgjg6QEFNTS6gbHJ-MaYsUBAiW5KYp2FoYICQBXJ0gIKamhALFiyA0AA) with slightly reduced precision to enable it to run with ATO's reduced memory allowance.

Single function with arguments `x`=input number, `f`=trigonometric function to inverse (one of `sin`, `cos` or `tan`).  Just within the 3rd-decimal place precision limit, but precision can be increased by increasing the `e8` & `e-7` in the code to `e9` & `e-8`.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 67 bytes

```r
\(x,f){while((f(F/T)-x)^2>1e-8)T=`if`(T-1,T+F-(F=F+1),F+(F=1));F/T}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY_BisIwEIbv-xSBvczQRK0gCFIvQp6gRxFLSdaAJpqkGhCfxEuF3TfxJXwbx61L2dNMvv-bGXK9-fbb2GPx00Qtpo_FEhLXeD5tzFYBaJDDEkXC1XieKzHFslgbvYZS5LzMpABZyCxHLjPqcsQZ6Zf3qnsNVTAWRoMJcjrxajgBxA9Kahf-JwS6JFYW3nzC6UH0kwW3U8zFjfJMN7aOxtnAomNkKR9pbOu--imV9r-7qPaQDILh0FReFX9LIGFajUkNBx97t7NI7_7Stl19Ag)

Generalized "inverse" function, which, with arguments `x`=input number and `f`=any function, will output a non-negative real number (if it exists) corresponding to the inverse of `f` applied to `x`, within a precision of `1e-4` (in other words, the difference between `f(inv(x,f))` and `x` is less than `1e-4`).

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES7), 94 bytes

Probably not the golfiest way, especially for edge cases.

Returns `[atan(x), acos(x), asin(x)]`.

```javascript
x=>[(p=1.571,g=x=>1/x?x/(h=k=>k+++k+(k>>9?0:k*k*x*x/h(k)))``:p)(x),c=2*g((1-x*x)**.5/++x),p-c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU9Nb8IwDL3zK6wewGnaNGF8aEwJp@0PcERIRAVKKEuqtkKRtv32LmE7MM1S/J7tp@f4om@6K1vT9Ll1h@NwkoOXaouNFGy@FFklQykKv/YFnmUtVU0prSnWSj2v@apO69SnvjhjTQjZ71cNQU@yUk7TClHkYUbSlM0LSkO7ycvdUDrbueuRXV2FCQB4@ATQvbZwJ6XrfkhnbEJeRn/keQya/8Y/EvVbnoHIIA@Ps2lMs5gWocXZ/J6XGYRB4CJqA04jcr5jJ9e@6vKMHqSCjxHA43bPerfpW2MrJKzRh02v2x5nBChMwo8nAU/hePauG8RbBoZEFzSggMN4HA5VIGANiS10Aiu4Bb83448HfCIPhotQXJyxeDclZPRFhm8)

#### Formulas

The arctangent is approximated with the continued fractions:

$$\arctan(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+\dfrac{(1x)^2}{3+\dfrac{(2x)^2}{5+\dfrac{(3x)^2}{7+\ddots}}}}$$

We then use:

$$\arccos(-1)=\pi\\\arccos(x)=2\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x}\right),\:-1<x\le1$$

and:

$$\arcsin(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos(x)$$

(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions))

Answer (score 4):

### Pascal, <s>162</s> 194 bytes

“Extended Pascal” (ISO standard 10206) defines that `complex` numbers are part of the language.
When calling one of these functions, a `real` argument is automatically promoted to a `complex` value (because the formal parameter list says the `function` requires a `complex` number).

```pascal
const i=cmplx(0,1);type r=complex;function s(x:r):r;begin s:=−i*ln(sqrt(1−x*x)+i*x);end;function c(x:r):r;begin c:=−i*ln(sqrt(x*x−1)+x);end;function t(x:r):r;begin t:=i/2*ln((1−i*x)/(1+i*x));end
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
    const
        i = cmplx(0, 1);
    
    function arcsin(protected x: complex): complex;
        begin
            arcsin := −i * ln(sqrt(1 − sqr(x)) + i * x);
        end;
    
    function arccos(protected x: complex): complex;
        begin
            arccos := −i * ln(sqrt(sqr(x) − 1) + x);
        end;
    
    function arctan(protected x: complex): complex;
        begin
            arctan := i / 2 * ln((1 − i * x) / (1 + i * x));
        end;
```

Arc tangent is actually already part of the language.
Both in ISO standard 7185 (“Standard Pascal”) and ISO standard 10206 (“Extended Pascal”) the built-in function `arctan` is available.
Since `complex` numbers are defined by EP, only the latter accepts and can return `complex` values.

Comment: can you also add a non built-in solution for the `arctan` function

Comment: @bsoelch Certainly I _can_, but wouldn’t this defeat the purpose of [tag:code-golf]? There is no benefit in defining a custom `arctan` anyway: the built-in trigonometric functions (`sin`, `cos`, and `arctan`) can take and output `complex` numbers.

Comment: Answers outside the community wiki should not only use non built-ins

Comment: @bsoelch Not only do I (from a software engineering point of view) dislike _reimplementing_ built-in functionality, but doesn’t this amount to a penalty? You know, I cannot add “Pascal” to the community wiki post, because only `arctan` is a built-in function.

Comment: Can't test, but would something like this work? `arcsin := arctan(x / sqrt(1 − sqr(x)));` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions)

Comment: You could add `arctan` to the community wiki and add a comment that the other two functions are not built-in

Comment: @corvus_192 Thank you for your suggestion, but this formula will require that the divisor is non-zero.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 172 bytes

```perl
sub asin{n(@_,\&CORE::sin)}
sub acos{n(@_,\&CORE::cos)}
sub atan{n(@_,sub{sin(@_)/cos(pop)})}
sub n{$f=pop;$x=1;$x+=(&$f($x)-$_[0])/((&$f($x-1e-6)-&$f($x))*1e6)for 1..9;$x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZJfa8IwFMWf109xcdHmbmltmBOm6yYMn/Yg9FVFqiabsP6h7aBS/Oz1pnai7GXLQ8g9J7/kXJJUZV@PdZ1/ryHMd3EV88lKLHpvs2A6GpGAB6vxNkl@7ZHw4xVhy1FVEUNL7JPP0yTFQ7srrpj2SRiz0pc03fu8xzRnJTpsNfeW2Oet4EjlDNFpXbyTaog6yUC67hOBh9oU0R5YofICuAU0eBSmc7BNC7YAk4GuycJ4yx9cOegPEMF/AVbCUphzpIfiiqO0xJnM/@OodeJo/gOHVYNGe860YKVgqkzRnzRtjFsL2EdSgA9t8yc5zXZxoaHTzakg34euHLhSaippHyl4KdGxalOo7aW23Wl9rhdxR1g34ZqaJdZpcsAzeK7nSbj9jJpLzXgFe/ZuwwjsaRDMApsok5ugJrw449bpjc1H@PX@9RE)

Uses Perl's builtin trig functions `sin` and `cos`. Since asin, acos and atan aren't builtin, they're rather found in the core lib [Math::Trig](https://perldoc.perl.org/Math::Trig), but here they're instead written in a [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)-ish solver in `sub n`.

**Or 259 bytes:**

```perl
sub si{my$x=pop;abs$x<1e-8?$x:2*si($x/2)*co($x/2)}
sub co{my$x=pop;abs$x<1e-8?1:co($x/2)**2-si($x/2)**2}
sub ta{&si/&co}
sub asi{n(@_,'si')}
sub aco{n(@_,'co')}
sub ata{n(@_,'ta')}
sub n{$f=pop;$x=1;$x+=(&$f($x)-$_[0])/((&$f($x-1e-6)-&$f($x))*1e6)for 1..9;$x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPfT7MwFH2Wv@LG1dFiYXTOfbqJ@uKTMSZ7VWOQFSX5@JEVE@ayv33eFsbQuT5A77nn3HO5LYVc/D/fbNTnG6hklS5JFRR5MQ3fFKmuhHQvbkg1GToqoaQaDJkT5fVmbWlJlP8pEZMtzXGGbqt1hrWqDFd9lQz6UV7HITpn9PaV2yqxm8ohlq6xKG8xFNZYGW6xbEViY49dCHycBrRPYjRkLnl98l/YgDaAi62NmdtkmSPkmMX5AoTnXaJwvflUEh5kmidfcgppvaGmpU6ou5laWpcugZRSlUAtwPUENn6HzXGMVHj@iEFwDXoDLxygh2xMsN/UbJ/bK/BIlMnt6GjLcdrqIF3ndnScD8cx77H37X3P/2cYetNltI4HGVuTg4SOybghjA9Y/JnfGfxMp2Hxozwe/SLM5vTMEyO8Z4ZLKj0cPNsz39RjK/NKl5TEnFScyKpgwa05wWmTAvKelxBAc0VquFgkWRnD8YnCAPMBnIiRJ0SMIfIQYV0Iy8qolPMuNk/iuI2fs2NuHeHPQrWba/qAKz07X0DvIzWmet2A/XhvwwTsu9nscWajSveNItM8b@XWevMN)

...which replaces Perl's `sin` and `cos` with `si` and `co` that uses the property that sin(x) = x and cos(x) = 1 for small x and the formulas for half angles.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>132</s> 125 bytes

```
ＮθＮη⊞υ¹⊞υ∧›⁰ηθ≔⁰ζ≔²εＦ⁵⁰«≔₂⊕Ｘε²δ≔¹ιＦχ«≔⊘⁺ιδι≔₂×ιδδ»≔∨⎇⊕η⁼›⁰§υη⎇η›θ§υ⁰›§υ¹θ›⁰§υ¹±¹δＵＭυ⁺κ×××δε§υ¬λ∨λ±¹≧⁺×∨η¹×δ∕ειζ≧×₂⊕×εεθ≦⊘ε»Ｉζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZLBTsMwDIbP9ClyTKQMtZN24jQBgh0Y09gLhNUsEWm6pumAoT17cdJ2S6VxqeL49xf7d7dS2G0pdNsuzL5xy6Z4B0srdpfEscR41dSSNpxk0XlucvpkQTjUpJxIxknFMD@va7Uz/up4iaacAEYfpSV0ljLym9z0mbeqERbWZenowmwtFGAc5HRVfiEXOJkyhuQci4eKjBPlwwDLOtiQexb64Kt1U1Ply1gvvvLcRhVwUYUXTudHXi3dgDXC/oza8lM@IkLX8exztzA5fHtXpGcNlZKTQVWNVKlXDanoPutMvOTG8Cx4sYQd5mh27vpF7O/LohC4EBSF2T@xiTBe/M39EkbAJdqgAxTn1TGasZ7c@bFWO@mCrQMYC2TX8Bn@oA4qB780FZjHK4gg5uSfrXco8H2yYEUM6Jfb/UmnZGWVcfRe1I4esdm2naS3syRrJwf9Bw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the function as the second argument where `-1=atan`, `0=asin` and `1=acos`. Explanation: Uses [CORDIC](https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/py_src/cordic/cordic.html) to calculate the inverse functions. Edit: Switched to single-angle CORDIC for `asin` and `acos` to save 7 bytes.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the real value.

```
Ｎη
```

Input the function code.

```
⊞υ¹
```

Start with `z[0]=1`.

```
⊞υ∧›⁰ηθ
```

Start with `z[1]=0`, except for `atan`, where the input is used.

```
≔⁰ζ
```

Start with a resulting angle of `0`.

```
≔²ε
```

Start with `2` as the first power of `0.5`. This is needed for `acos` to work with negative inputs, but doesn't affect `asin` or `atan`.

```
Ｆ⁵⁰«
```

Loop `50` times, as unfortunately `10` isn't accurate enough.

```
≔₂⊕Ｘε²δ≔¹ιＦχ«≔⊘⁺ιδι≔₂×ιδδ»
```

Start calculating the `atan` of the power of `0.5`. (Yes, I could do the `atan` separately, but that would duplicate code, increasing my byte count.)

```
≔∨⎇⊕η⁼›⁰§υη⎇η›θ§υ⁰›§υ¹θ›⁰§υ¹±¹δ
```

Determine whether we are increasing or decreasing the angle.

```
ＵＭυ⁺κ×××δε§υ¬λ∨λ±¹
```

Rotate `z` by the `atan` of the power of `0.5`.

```
≧⁺×∨η¹×δ∕ειζ
```

Update the angle.

```
≧×₂⊕×εεθ
```

Compensate for rotation's scaling factor (no effect for `atan`). Note that in a real FPGA you would approximate the square root but that doesn't help me here.

```
≦⊘ε
```

Get the next power of `0.5`.

```
»Ｉζ
```

Output the final angle.